Equivalent definition of barycentric subdivision of standard simplex
In Algebraic Topology by Allen Hatcher, the barycenter of the simplex $[v_0,...,v_n]$ is the point $b=\sum_i t_iv_i$ where $t_i=\frac{1}{n+1}$, and the barycentric subdivision of $[v_0,...,v_n]$ is the decomposition of it into $n$-simplices $[b,w_0,...,w_{n-1}]$ where, inductively, $[w_0,...,w_{n-1}]$ is an $(n-1)$-simplex in the barycentric subdivision of a face $[v_0,...,\hat{v}_i,...,v_n]$ (the hat represents omitting that vector). The induction starts with the case $n=0$ when the barycentric subdivision of $[v_0]$ is just $[v_0]$ itself.
In class, my professor gave three alternative definition of a barycentric subdivision for a standard simplex $\Delta^n$ which are
(a)  Simplex $A$ where its vertices is given by
$$b_i^\sigma=\dfrac{e_{\sigma(0)}+...+e_{\sigma(i)}}{i+1}$$
for $\sigma\in S_{n+1}$ (the symmetric group) and $i=0,...,n$, and $\{e_0,...,e_n\}$ are the vertices of $\Delta^n$.
(b) Cones centered at the center of $\Delta^n$ over the barycentric decompositions of the faces.
(c) The set
$$C=\{(t_0,...,t_n)\mid \sum_{i=0}^nt_i=1,\text{ },t_i\geq0,\text{ }t_{\sigma(0)}\leq t_{\sigma(1)}\leq...\leq t_{\sigma(n)}\}.$$
I understand what definitions (a) and (c) means. However, I am having trouble what (b) means. Is it the same definition as the one in Hatcher? If so, what does the term cone mean. If not, then how does this process work? For example, if I have $\Delta^2$, do I the barycentric subdivision (using Hatcher's definition above) on $C\Delta^2$ with $\Delta^2$ identified at $\Delta^2\times\{1\}$?

What's your question?

@BenSteffan My question is what definition (b) means and also if the proof is correct.

Then please edit your question to explicitly say so. I've gone ahead and added the [tag:solution-verification] tag, given your comment; please make sure you comply with the rules written in its tag description, in particular the following: ' "Is this proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.'
